# My first Shiny App in R - Time serie request

Tags: plot, shiny, time-series, rstudio

I have a table like this:

```
    EmpNum      Sym   Jan_C Feb_C Mar_C
    34335333    2200    400 300     200
    34334533    2243    300 200    100
    2424142     5025    200 100     400
    1023231     5021    204 532    2300
```

And I'm intrested of ploting time series according to the selection of the user. He will select EmpNum and Sym and the output will be a plot of this serie from Jan to Mar. I Started writing this:

```
    **ui.R**

    shinyUI(
 pageWithSidebar (
   headerPanel ("My Shiny App"), 

sidebarPanel (
 selectInput("Employee", "Please Select An Employee Number:",
              choices=data$EmpNum,2424142),
 selectInput ("Symbol", "Please Select Salary Symbol:",
                           choices=data$Sym, 5025)
),
mainPanel(plotOutput("myPlot"))

)
)
```

And:

```
**server.r:**

shinyServer (
 function (input,output,session){
     output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
     data <- read.csv(file="workers.csv", header=T)
     seData  <- as.numeric(data[which(data$EmpNum==input$Employee & data$Sym==input$Symbol),][3:5])
     Et  <- ts(seData, start=1,end=3)
     plot(Et,col="blue")
 })
})
```

Update : I fixed the problem. Any ides how to change the input in a way that if the user will select for example the value '34335333' the only values that will show up for Sym will be: '2200' and '2243'.

This my first shiny app that I am making. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using dynamic inputs. I mocked up data since you did not provide a reproducible problem:

**server.R**

```
# create mock data
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(EmpNum = rep(seq(500), each = 5), Sym = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 500), dp1 = runif(500), dp2 = runif(500), dp3 = runif(500))

# remove some columns to test reactive selection
n <- nrow(data)
droprows <- sample(seq(n), floor(n*0.7))
data <- data[-droprows, ]

shinyServer (
  function (input,output,session){

    output$employee <- renderUI({
      selectInput("Employee", "Please Select An Employee Number:",
                  choices = sort(data$EmpNum))
    })

    output$symbol <- renderUI({
      if (!is.null(input$Employee)){
        selectInput ("Symbol", "Please Select Salary Symbol:",
                    choices = sort(unique(data[data$EmpNum == input$Employee, ]$Sym)))  
      }
    })


    output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
      if (all(!is.null(input$Employee), !is.null(input$Symbol))){

      seData  <- as.numeric(data[data$EmpNum == input$Employee & data$Sym == as.character(input$Symbol),][3:5])
      Et  <- ts(seData, start=1,end=3)
      plot(Et,col="blue")
      }
    })
  })
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar (
    headerPanel ("My Shiny App"), 

    sidebarPanel (
      uiOutput("employee"),
      uiOutput("symbol")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("myPlot"))

  )
)
```